# Drop database return "Error dropping database errno: 66" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, osx-lion, root, drop-database

Consider:

```
DROP DATABASE db_name;
ERROR 1010 (HY000): Error dropping database (can't rmdir './db_name', errno: 66)
```

The problem is that I don't know where the file/directory is located - this file is missing in **/usr/local/mysql/bin/**...

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: `datadir=` in my.cnf should point you to your data directory.

Comment: I just want to point out that happened to me in phpmyadmin with case-sensitive database name, for example if I try to drop `my_DATAbase` I can see that error. The folder name is `my_DATAbase` but phpmyadmin is trying to delete the folder `my_database`.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
mysql> drop database DB_NAME; 
ERROR 1010 (HY000): Error dropping database 
(can't rmdir './DB_NAME', errno: 66)
```

1. Find the database directory:
   `mysql -e "select @@datadir"` -> `/usr/local/mysql/data/`
2. Go to the DataBase folder: `cd /usr/local/mysql/data/`
3. Delete DB folder of the DB with the issue (in this case: `sudo rm -rf DB_NAME`)

Comment: Hello, the first point - I get only `/usr/local/bin/mysql`, `cd /usr/local/bin/mysql` => `Not a directory`

Comment: You have your mysql in a different directory...then check datadir= in my.cnf should point you to your data directory

Comment: How can I display it? Where is it located?

Comment: Here are possible locations of the my.cnf file for version 5.5 on Mac OS X:

/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
defaults-extra-file (the file specified with --defaults-extra-file=path, if any)
~/.my.cnf

Comment: Just incase you face issue deleting the folder because of permission issues you may do that as an admin/root user. It worked for me. Thanks    Robert

Comment: mysql -e "select @@datadir"

Comment: In my case i'm running in local AMPPS and i have the same problem.
The only way to fix it was to manually delete the database folder in 
/Applications/AMPPS/var/ "the-folder-nameo-db"

Comment: Type:  mysql -e "select @@datadir" 
This will show you where your database(s) exist. 
Goto that folder shown from the command above.
Delete the corrupted db by typing: rm -rf yourDbName 
Thank you @Robert Rozas

Comment: If you get an access denied error, you have to execute this command as a root user (or an user with root access): `mysql -u root -p -e "select @@datadir"` you will be asked for your password, after that the datadir will show up.

Comment: On OSX, my database folders are in my database directory, i.e. `/usr/local/var/mysql/ ` not in a `data` subdirectory. Deleting these solved my issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using XAMPP in OSX the data directory would be at

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI for mac users with normal mysql server:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -pPASSWORD  -e "select @@datadir"
```

Comment: How would this drop the a db table?