# MySQL Workbench not allowing for me to drop a database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is quite odd, it's happening only for a some Databases, but I get this error:

```
ERROR 1010: Error dropping database (can't rmdir './main', errno: 66)
SQL Statement:
drop database `Main`
```

This happens over and over, even on Root user...

This happens even if there is nothing in the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527054/mysql-drop-database-return-error-dropping-database-errno-66

Comment: Possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584458/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-test-errno-17

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky and mserioli:  Niether of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, and it wasn't all that hard, using the OS X terminal I entered this in:

```
open /usr/local/mysql/data/
```

then, I just deleted the folders. An admin password was required though.

Thanks to anyone that offered to help

Comment: I got this `The file /usr/local/mysql/data does not exist.` when running your command.

Comment: @ihue This was posted like 1.75 years ago.  I don't use Mac OS anymore and MySQL could have updated and changed by then.  Try looking at the posts linked in the comments of the question, or try the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> drop database DB_NAME; 
ERROR 1010 (HY000): Error dropping database 
(can't rmdir './DB_NAME', errno: 66)
```

1) mysql -e "select @@datadir" -> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

2) Go to DB folder: cd /usr/local/mysql/data/

3) Delete DB folder of DB with issue (in this case: "DB_NAME")

Source [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527054/mysql-drop-database-return-error-dropping-database-errno-66)

Comment: You literally copied that, and I said it didn't work in the questions comments.